# Canny Edge Image - Noise removal

Tags: image-processing, edge-detection

I have a Canny edge detected image of a ball (see link below) which contains a lot of noisy edges.  What are the best image processing techniques that I can use to remove these noisy edges without removing the edges belonging to the ball?

Original image

[image: original]

Canny edge image

[image: canny]

Many thanks everyone in advance for your help and advice, much appreciated!

Ps I am trying to clean up the edge image prior to using the Circle Hough Transform to detect the ball.

Comment: It would be useful to see the original image. Canny has [three parameters as inputs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector), one of which is the size of the Gaussian blur filter used for pre-processing and the other two are thresholds that control the level of detail returned. I suspect you can improve the result with more suitable choices but would need the original image to be sure.

Comment: I'm auto-calculating Canny parameters as follows: 

  double high_thres = cv::threshold( orig_img, thres_img, 0, 255,    CV_THRESH_BINARY+CV_THRESH_OTSU );

lower thres = 0.1 * high_thres

cv::Canny(orig_img, cannyOP, lower_thres, high_thres);

If I go any lower than the 0.1 multiple for the 'lower_thres' I get too much noise, if I go higher, I lose the edges that belong to the ball.  This is taken from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292249/automatic-calculation-of-low-and-high-thresholds-for-the-canny-operation-in-open

Comment: Ok, then can you provide a link to the original image (I'll add it to your question)?

Comment: I will do no problem, but it will be later in the evening when I'm home :) Thanks.

Comment: Hi Roger, a little off topic, are there any other ways of detecting/tracking a ball (which may be occluded), that you know of, other than the Circle Hough Transform?

Comment: It depends on the image ;-) Other alternatives might be colour segmentation and tracking using mean shift or optical flow, or maybe template matching if you have a ground truth image of the ball. Let's see what the image looks like first, I'll await your update.

Comment: I am trying to detect and track arbitrary coloured balls, regardless of lighting levels and using grayscale images only.  I'll post the image later.  Many thanks for your advice :)

Comment: what is your scenario? do you want to automate the ball detection? do you have any real-time issues? is user-interaction allowed?

Comment: Roger, please see the links above.  I've recreated the images since I no longer had the original to match the first image I posted.

Answer (score 10):

The best option is to filter the image before applying the edge detector. In order to keep the sharp edges you need to use a more sophisticated filter than the Gaussian blur.

Two easy options are the [Bilateral filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilateral_filter) or the [Guided filter](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/jiansun/papers/GuidedFilter_ECCV10.pdf). These two filters are very easy to implement and they provide good results in most cases: gaussian noise removal preserving edges. If you need something more powerful, you can try the filter [BM3D](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~foi/GCF-BM3D/), which is one of the state-of-the-art filters, and you can find an open source implementation [here](http://www.ipol.im/pub/art/2012/l-bm3d/).

Answer (score 9):

Canny edge detection works best only after you set optimal threshold levels (lower and upper thresholds)

#### How do you set them?

- First, calculate the **median** of the gray scale image.
- Choose the optimal threshold values using the median of the image.

The following pseudo-code shows you how its done:

```
v = np.median(gray_img)
sigma = 0.33

#---- apply optimal Canny edge detection using the computed median----
lower_thresh = int(max(0, (1.0 - sigma) * v))
upper_thresh = int(min(255, (1.0 + sigma) * v))
```

Set `lower_thresh` and `upper_thresh` as the parameters for the canny edge function.

`sigma` is set to `0.33` because in statistics along a distribution curve, values lying between 33% from the start and end of the curve are considered. Values lying beyond and below this curve as considered to be outliers.

This is what I got for your image:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The best way to remove those is probably not to have them in the first place if you can. If the lines are noisy artifacts in the image apply a smoothing filter such as a Gaussian to level the image out. -> [Gaussian filter info](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/gsmooth.htm)

Removing them once they are there is tricky and would probably involve some higher level shape recognition stuff

Comment: Canny has a built-in Gaussian blur - there's no need for a separate step.

Comment: but if the smoothing isn't strong enough you are still going to pick up artifacts, a pre-filtering stage (with a not necessarily gaussian filter) could help

Comment: Yes that's right, I was just pointing out that your suggestion of a Gaussian blur is already a part of the Canny algorithm.

Comment: I guess there's no way to modify OpenCV's built-in gaussian for the Canny function? You need to complete this extra step?