# How to remove noise keeping edge information?

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing

I have two images, one is original image and another one is canny edge image. I like to remove noise actually from the original image. So I tried canny edge, it looks ok, but still have some noises. How can I remove those noises further in canny edge image or the main reason is just want to remove noise and keep those numbers.
I found one discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18194870/canny-edge-image-noise-removal). They suggest to use Bilateral filter or the Guided filter or BM3D filter before applying Canny edge. I applied bilateral filter before applying Canny edge. Still have some noises. How can I improve?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried a slightly larger Gaussian kernel?

Comment: I tried this org.opencv.core.Size size = new Size(15,15);
Imgproc.GaussianBlur(roi_gray, roi_gray, size, 0.5); But still the same.

Comment: Sorry, I mean the kernel size you pass to Canny, which has a Gaussian convolution built-in. Another thing to try would be to convert to gray-intensity and apply a different (higher) thresholding. You may have to experiment with thresholding to see how it works out.

Comment: The original image has 0 and 255 only.

Comment: Yes, since it was B/W, and *initially* you would have two levels in the converted image too. But when filtering, you'll get more shades, and it will be easier to distinguish between speckled noise and continuous signal. Try converting in gray in Windows Paint and resize to 50% size to see a *very* rough version of what I mean.