# Fill Broken and Damaged Texts - OPENCV

Tags: c++14, tesseract, opencv3.0

I am trying to extract the text from an image using openCV and tesseract.
Since, we need to pass a clean image to tesseract to fetch the text properly with accuracy.  But I am facing an issue related to preprocessing of an image using opencv.

How can i join the texts and get proper text to to pass to the tesseract?

**image1(ORIGINAL IMAGE)**

[image]

**image2(PROCESSED IMAGE)**.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connect close-by dots for OCR (some hints asked, e.g. using morphological operations)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47391811/connect-close-by-dots-for-ocr-some-hints-asked-e-g-using-morphological-operat)

Comment: Thanks @DmitriiZ. for your help. This link help it out to some extent. But still I am facing the same issue. Below I am attaching the image I got after using this link. Please help.

Comment: You forgot to attach the image.

Comment: here is the link for image - https://ibb.co/jtTJuK