# Adaptive parameter for Canny Edge

Tags: opencv, graphics, computer-vision, canny-operator

I'm using a project using OpenCV for detecting a card that will be place on a atable.
I have successfully detect it using Canny Edge. However, for different image the parameter must be tuned manually. I wish for my project to be worked with every image without manually tune the parameter. What Should I do?

Comment: what's the difference between the images? maybe some kind of normalization (white balance, brightness, contrast) of the input image and fixed canny parameters will give you the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your image consist of Distinct Background & Foreground, You can get the threshold for that automatically as follows explained in this paper http://www.academypublisher.com/proc/isip09/papers/isip09p109.pdf.

1. Compute Otsu's threshold + Binary threshold for your image.
2. Use the Otsu's threshold value as higher threshold for Canny's algorithm.

#### CODE:

```
Mat mCanny_Gray,mThres_Gray;
Mat mSrc_Gray=imread("Test.bmp",0);

double CannyAccThresh = threshold(mSrc_Gray,mThres_Gray,0,255,CV_THRESH_BINARY|CV_THRESH_OTSU);

double CannyThresh = 0.1 * CannyAccThresh;

Canny(mSrc_Gray,mCanny_Gray,CannyThresh,CannyAccThresh);
imshow("mCanny_Gray",mCanny_Gray);
```

You can also refer [this thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292249/automatic-calculation-of-low-and-high-thresholds-for-the-canny-operation-in-open)

Comment: What preprocessing technique do I need for the image before I apply your answer? Is converting to Grayscale is sufficient or I need to apply some thresholding as well?

Comment: For all edge detection techniques you need to apply smoothing e.g Gaussian smoothing before applying edge detection. It is good to convert your image into a Gray Scale Image.

Comment: Two parameters having a 10 fold difference seems too much to me. Could you comment on this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Helmholtz principle to adaptively find the lower and higher thresholds of the Canny edge detector.

You can refer the following [link](http://cvrs.whu.edu.cn/projects/cannyLines/) for the paper and the implementation in OpenCV C++.