# getting error in canny edge detection

Tags: python, opencv

i am trying to write a code using opencv python that automatically get canny threshold values instead of doing them manually every time.

```
img= cv2.imread('micro.png',0)
output = np.zeros(img.shape, img.dtype)
# Otsu's thresholding
ret2,highthresh = cv2.threshold(img,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
lowthresh=0.1*highthres
edges = cv2.Canny(img,output,lowthresh,highthresh)
cv2.imshow('canny',edges)
```

i am getting this error
"File "test2.py", line 14, in 
    edges = cv2.Canny(img,output,lowthresh,highthresh)
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars"

can anyone help me to sort out this error.thankx in advance

Comment: I think it has problem with png file, I also get the same error. try converting the image to JPG

Answer (score 2):

It seems like `cv2.threshold` returns the detected edges, and `Canny` applies them to the image. The code below worked for me and gave me some nice detected edges in my image.

```
import cv2

cv2.namedWindow('canny demo')

img= cv2.imread('micro.png',0)
ret2,detected_edges = cv2.threshold(img,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
edges = cv2.Canny(detected_edges,0.1,1.0)
dst = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img,mask = edges)
cv2.imshow('canny',dst)

if cv2.waitKey(0) == 27:
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: this is not giving me the require output.and i have to work on more then one pictures thats why i can't set threshold values everytime for that i got the concept from here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292249/automatic-calculation-of-low-and-high-thresholds-for-the-canny-operation-in-open. but it is not working for me

Answer (score 1):

You are running:

```
cv2.Canny(img,output,lowthresh,highthresh)
```

It is looking for

```
cv2.Canny(img,lowthresh,highthresh,output)
```

I think the ordering changed in some version, because I have seen references to both.