# Canny edge detector with a single threshold value

Tags: matlab, opencv, edge-detection, threshold

I'm trying to port some Matlab code to C++.
I've come across this line:

```
edges = edge(gray,'canny',0.1);
```

The output for the sample image is a completely black image. I want to reproduce the same behaviour using cv::Canny. What values should I use for low threshold and high threshold?

Sample:
[image: Sample Image]

Output:
[image: Output]

Comment: Usually depends upon the type of image but you may like to look at these : http://www.kerrywong.com/2009/05/07/canny-edge-detection-auto-thresholding/ or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292249/automatic-calculation-of-low-and-high-thresholds-for-the-canny-operation-in-open

Comment: I tried the first one already, and it detected lots of edges where the matlab code detected none.

Comment: for clarification: are you asking how to put that 0.1 in opencv?

Comment: post input and output images in lossless format (.png) please.

Comment: I want to know what matlab is doing with that 0.1.

Answer (score 0):

In the line above you have not defined a threshold, probably it takes zero then, thus delivering a black picture. Also, you use a sigma of 0.1 which means virtually no Gauss Blur in the first Canny step. Within Matlab you can get an optimized threhold by:

```
 [~, th] = edge(gray,'canny');
```

and then apply the optimized threshold th multiplied by some factor f (from my experience f should be between 1-3), you have to try out:

```
 edges=edge(gray,'canny',f*th,'both', sigma);
```

sigma is sqrt(2) by default (you used 0.1 above). Following remarks:

- Matlab calculated the optimized threshold as a percentile of the distribution of intensity gradients (you can see the construction of edge() if you enter "edit edge", if I remember correctly)
- the above parameter th is a vector consisting of the low and high threshold. Matlab always uses low_threshold = 0.4* high_threshold

Comment: So, it's the same as cv::Canny(m_gray, edges, 255*0.4, 255*1)? It's giving me the same black output at least. I didn't write the matlab code, it's just there. All I want to make sure my code gives the same output, even if it's a black image.

Comment: I think the equivalent openCv code is: GaussianBlur(m_gray, m_gray, Size(9,9), 0.1, 0.1);
Canny(m_gray, edges, 255*0.4, 255*1); Is that right?

Comment: I checked the Matlab docu and found the following syntax: BW = edge(I,method,threshold). Tried it with a grayvalue picture, it gives a normal canny edge, white edges on black ground. So 0.1 is the high treshold (max is 1; i.e. with 0.99 you just get a few edges, with 0.01 you get a million edges.

Comment: 0.1 seems to be the sigma, which is used for smoothing. It's not the high threshold, if I set the high threshold to 0.1 and the low to 0.04 I will get a lot of edges.

Comment: No, in the above Matlab syntax 0.1 is the high threshold. That's what I say, 0.1 gives a normal Canny picture - I tried it in Matlab.

Comment: we speak about the third syntax here: mathworks.com/help/images/ref/edge.html?refresh=true

Comment: But edge(gray,'canny',0.1) gives me a black image. If 0.1 was the high threshold it would give me lots of edges.

Comment: I don't know open cv. In Matlab however thresholds are scaled to the range [0,1]. It might be that cv uses [0, 255].